# jQuery - How do I change view based on mouseOver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I made the home page of [my site](http://rouviere.com) so that when you mouse over the different service offerings that the related image would also display. However when Malsup's hosting of Cycle came off github the function was lost.

Here is the code I am using that worked before but no longer works correctly. The slideshow still cycles through, but the mouseover function does not work correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    pager : '#slideshow-nav',
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    speed: 1000,
    delay:  3000,
    timeout: 9000,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    // return sel string for existing anchor
    return '.features ul li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
},
allowPagerClickBubble: true 
});
});
</script>
```

What changes do I need to make to get it working again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 'command' of the plugin libary, it will do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#skills li").click(function(){

        id = $(this).attr('id');

        imgIndexToJump = id.substr(1); //extracting number as index from id
        imgIndexToJump = parseInt(imgIndexToJump, 10);

        $('.slideshow').cycle('goto', imgIndexToJump);
    });
});

</script>
```

assign ids to ur list in skills like this and it will work.

```
<ul id="skills">
<li id="a0">
    a1-data
</li>
<li id="a2">
    a1-data
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Bsienn, I tried the code above and all of the slides show simultaneously on top of each other, so I think something is missing.

Comment: I have used class in jquery selector, plz change $(".slideshow") to $("#slideshow"), let me update my ans again also.

Comment: It still does not work. In reviewing your code, I think there may be some misunderstanding about what is supposed to happen. The slideshow appears normal now and cycles through correctly. What is missing is the mouseover that causes the slideshow to advance to the selected slide, not just pause or continue.

Comment: Yes i misunderstood, i though u just needded to pause on moreover. please let me check if i could come up with a solution. Other thing is u need to specify id to each element, so we could use to jump on that slide.

Comment: Hi Bsienn, I did a some more research and found that things had changed with the jQuery Cycle module. The original code was found on Github and that got moved. So I downloaded the latest version from the website and now everything is working correctly. I appreciate your help. Thank you.